# Format date string programatically in DevExpress gridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress

I have a date that is displayed like so in a gridview from DevExpress : 20071031 (YYYYMMDD*) and I would like it to appear as 2007/10/31 in the gridview.

*Data was imported from sql server table as Varchar.

I've tried the following but it doesn't do anything, date still appears as YYYMMDD.

```
gridview.Columns("CloseDate").DisplayFormat.FormatType = FormatType.DateTime
gridview.Columns("CloseDate").DisplayFormat.FormatString = "d"
```

I also know that the following would work to convert a string to the required Date format (However I can not apply this to my situation).

```
Dim strDate As String = DateTime.ParseExact("20071117", "yyyyMMdd", Nothing).ToString("MM\/dd\/yyyy")
```

Comment: If you are using SQL to retrieve the data
 CONVERT(date,'20071031',101) would do the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DevExpress support team provided me with the following solution:

```
Private Sub gridview_CustomColumnDisplayText(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs) Handles gridview.CustomColumnDisplayText
       If e.Column.FieldName = "CloseDate" Then
           Dim strDate As String = DateTime.ParseExact(e.Value, "yyyyMMdd", Nothing).ToString("MM\/dd\/yyyy")
           e.DisplayText = strDate
       End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you can't use ParseExact but maybe you can use this:

```
    Dim D$ = "20150522"
    Dim mData =  D.substring(4,2) & "/" & D.substring(6) & "/" & D.substring(0,4)
```